# Tomcat + NetBeans + JAX-WS Sample Project results in javax.xml.ws.WebServiceException

Tags: java, tomcat, netbeans, jax-ws

I created a simple Java EE project in NetBeans (File -> New Project -> Java Web -> Web Application).

In the new created project I added a Web Service and called "CesaService". Here is the source:

```
package com.convista.jcesa.webservice;

import javax.jws.WebMethod;
import javax.jws.WebParam;
import javax.jws.WebService;

@WebService(serviceName = "CesaService")
public class CesaService {

    @WebMethod(operationName = "hello")
    public String hello(@WebParam(name = "name") String txt) {
        return "Hello " + txt + " !";
    }
}
```

NetBean then generated the following files:

sun-jaxws.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<endpoints version="2.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jax-ws/ri/runtime">
  <endpoint implementation="com.convista.jcesa.webservice.CesaService" name="CesaService" url-pattern="/CesaService"/>
</endpoints>
```

web.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="3.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd">
    <listener>
        <listener-class>com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.servlet.WSServletContextListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>CesaService</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.servlet.WSServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>CesaService</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/CesaService</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <session-config>
        <session-timeout>
            30
        </session-timeout>
    </session-config>
</web-app>
```

My server is the shipped Tomcat 7.0.22.0. When I start the project I get the following error:

```
Schwerwiegend: WSSERVLET11: failed to parse runtime descriptor: javax.xml.ws.WebServiceException: class com.convista.jcesa.webservice.jaxws.Hello do not have a property of the name name
javax.xml.ws.WebServiceException: class com.convista.jcesa.webservice.jaxws.Hello do not have a property of the name name
    at com.sun.xml.ws.server.sei.EndpointArgumentsBuilder$DocLit.<init>(EndpointArgumentsBuilder.java:531)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.server.sei.EndpointMethodHandler.createArgumentsBuilder(EndpointMethodHandler.java:133)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.server.sei.EndpointMethodHandler.<init>(EndpointMethodHandler.java:106)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.server.sei.SEIInvokerTube.<init>(SEIInvokerTube.java:82)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.server.EndpointFactory.createEndpoint(EndpointFactory.java:219)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.api.server.WSEndpoint.create(WSEndpoint.java:505)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.DeploymentDescriptorParser.parseAdapters(DeploymentDescriptorParser.java:253)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.DeploymentDescriptorParser.parse(DeploymentDescriptorParser.java:147)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.servlet.WSServletContextListener.contextInitialized(WSServletContextListener.java:124)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4723)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext$1.call(StandardContext.java:5226)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext$1.call(StandardContext.java:5221)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:334)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:166)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
Caused by: javax.xml.bind.JAXBException: name is not a valid property on class com.convista.jcesa.webservice.jaxws.Hello
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl.getElementPropertyAccessor(JAXBContextImpl.java:971)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.server.sei.EndpointArgumentsBuilder$DocLit.<init>(EndpointArgumentsBuilder.java:520)
    ... 16 more

Jun 13, 2012 2:31:35 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal
Schwerwiegend: Error listenerStart
Jun 13, 2012 2:31:35 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal
Schwerwiegend: Context [/FST] startup failed due to previous errors
Jun 13, 2012 2:31:35 PM com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.servlet.WSServletContextListener contextDestroyed
Information: WSSERVLET13: JAX-WS context listener destroyed
Jun 13, 2012 2:31:36 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext reload
Information: Reloading Context with name [/FST] is completed
```

Do you have any idea what causes this? I don't want and have a class `com.convista.jcesa.webservice.jaxws.Hello` and don't understand where it is referenced.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 public String hello(@WebParam(name = "name") String txt) {
```

should be

```
 public String hello(@WebParam(name = "name") String name) {
```

Comment: Thx... Did not check that :) Stupid!